Error in R Markdown PDF Knitting: "Missing $ Inserted" with stargazer
I'm encountering an error when knitting my R Markdown file to a PDF. The error message is as follows:
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.739 ... \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.046^{***}  (0.003)}
                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.04... 

Try to find the following text in hw10.Rmd:
  ... \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.046^{***}  (0.003)} 

You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r ` in hw10.Rmd (see the above hint). See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info.

After some troubleshooting, I traced the issue to the stargazer table in my R Markdown file. Here's the relevant code:
m3 <-
  glm.nb(
    dv ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4,
    data = df,
    control = glm.control(maxit = 1000)
  )

 # Model4
 m4 <- 
   glm.nb(
     dv ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5,
                data = df,
                control =glm.control(maxit =1000))

stargazer(
  m3, m4,
  title = "title",
  align = TRUE,
  header = FALSE,
  dep.var.labels = c("Model 1"),
  type = stargazer_opt,  # Explicitly ensure LaTeX output
  star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001),  # Define custom significance levels
  omit.table.layout = "l",
  no.space = F  # Remove extra spacing
)

After some investigation, I identified that the problem is related to the formatting of "theta" in the output table. Interestingly, adding the following option resolves the error:
omit.stat = "theta",

However, this workaround omits the theta statistic, which is an important part of my analysis and not a viable long-term solution.
Question:
Is there a better way to fix this issue without omitting critical parts of the table (like the theta statistic)?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.
I'm encountering an error when knitting my R Markdown file to a PDF.
And the ony solution I found was to omit "theta" from the table output.

‘stargazer’ is an all-round terrible package. I strongly recommend against using it. Use anything else instead, e.g. ‘modelsummary’ or ‘texreg’.

We can't run your code without more context.  Please post something that is self-contained and reproducible.
